# Fonts don't look right in IE after jQuery fadeIn

Tags: jquery

When I dynamically load content into a div and fadeIn (or show or slideDown), the fonts don't look very clear in IE.  The fonts of the preloaded contents look just fine, however.

I hove noticed this happening with scriptaculous in IE also.

Does anyone have any ideas?

No problems in Firefox.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work in v1.3:

```
$('#foo').fadeOut(function() {
  if (! $.support.opacity) {
    this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
  }
});
```

In earlier versions, you'd need to do:

```
$('#foo').fadeOut(function() {
  if ($.browser.msie) {
    this.style.removeAttribute('filter');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a background color on your div.  IE is very weird about opacity issues (or fading in, in this case), and setting a background color often helps with the effect.

Comment: Yes background color or image should fix.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice but unfortunately it isn't working for me.  As the effect is just eye candy for the website, I will resort to something that doesn't use opacity.

Comment: Yeah, these issues with IE can be very difficult to track down.  Good luck!